# I have a quiz and I want to get random questions (no repeat)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

As the title said, I have a huge problem with a PHP script. I want to extract(Get) random questions from my database and after that display it.I want the script to look like here: http://www.filebox.ro/download.php?key=d07a7jdcf2ouwu62
but with a MySQL database, and a admin dashboard for administrating questions and users.
Here is my script: http://fbx.ro/hxsztelz2chq1ekk

Here is my index.php
As you see on line 6 I don't know how to do it...
If you can teach me how to extract more than 1 question, like a quiz (aprox.:20 random questions)

```
 <?php
include("config.php");
?>
<?php
session_start();
$sql = "select * from quiz order by rand() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$question = "$row->questions";
$correctanswer = "$row->answers";
$money = '1';
$today = date('Y-m-d');
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
if (empty($_POST['answer']) || empty($_POST['id'])) {
echo '<p><span style="color: red;">Trebuie sa introduci un raspuns!</span></p>';
} else {

$answer = $_POST['answer'];
$sql_answer = "select * from quiz where id = '".addslashes($_POST["id"])."'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql_answer);
$row1 = mysql_fetch_object($result1);
$correctanswer = $row1->answers;
if (strtolower($answer) == strtolower($correctanswer))
{
echo 'Bravo, ai raspuns corect!';
$sql3= "INSERT INTO money VALUES ('','$money','$today')";
$res3 = mysql_query($sql3);
}
elseif (strtolower($answer) != strtolower($correctanswer)){

echo 'Raspuns gresit! Raspunsul corect era '.$correctanswer.'.';
}
}
}
?>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<?php echo "Intrebare: $question"; ?>
<br>
Raspuns: <input maxlength="60" name="answer" size="25" type="input">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Go">
<input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="TRUE">
</form>



REZULTATE:
<?php
$query1="SELECT money, data, Sum(money) AS SumOfMoney FROM money GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(data, '%M %d, %Y') = NOW()";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);
$row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
echo '<br>Total: '.$row1['SumOfMoney'].' puncte

';
?>
```

Comment: from @Volkan Ulukut's example you can delete "LIMIT 1" and get all the questions in the save page.Depends on what you want

Comment: I just want to get multiple questions from database random, no repeat.

Comment: Have someone here tested the code to understand what I say

Answer (score 2):

to get a random row from mysql database you can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

if you want to show them just once in each session you could use $_SESSION variable to keep already displayed questions and exclude those in your query.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE question_id NOT IN(1,4,6) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

if you need help using session to keep and exclude asked questions I can add answer to those as well.

Comment: ORDER BY RAND()? this can be a bit intensive couldn't it?

Comment: of course, if you could edit your post and include related parts of your script. it's time consuming to download all your code and pinpoint the part you are having problem with.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $max_value = 10;
                    $values = range(0, $max_value);
                    $counter = $max_value;
                    for($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++){
                        $rand_num = rand(1,$counter);
                        $current_number = $values[$rand_num];
                        array_splice($values, $rand_num, 1);
                        $counter--;

                        $query = "SELECT `question`, `op1`, `op2`, `op3`, `op4` FROM  `physics` WHERE `number`='$current_number'";
                        $query_run = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: 1) Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Read the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) _thoroughly_. 2) The `mysql` extension is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and _should not be used_.